# tried to load tidyverse but I'm met with "> library(tidyverse) Error in library(tidyverse) : there is no package called ‘tidyverse’"

Tags: r, tidyverse

I ran the `install.packages("tidyverse")` and the installation was done.

At the end the following errors and warnings appeared:

```
Error in read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :
  downloaded length 61440 != reported length 104968
2: In unzip(zipname, exdir = dest) : error 1 in extracting from zip file
3: In read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) :
  cannot open compressed file 'rprojroot/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it is because you
a) forgot to `install.packages('tidyverse')`
or
b) the 'install.packages('tidyverse')' failed

you may prefer the {pacman} approach
where `p_load()` checks whether installed,
then installs/loads or
just loads as needed